# Python: Creating a function that returns a list of scores in a competition

Tags: python

I'm having trouble creating a function with the following criteria. I think its a coincidence that my function is coming up with the right answer sometimes.

- In a competition, the rule to progress to the next round is “If a competitor earns a score equal to or greater than the person at the k-th place, they will advance to the next round given the score is greater than or equal to [limit]”.
- Write a function next_round(k, limit, scores).
- returns the number of people as integer progressing to the next round.
- scores is the list containing the scores of all other competitors, in no particular order.
- k is the maximum number of competitors advancing to the next round
- limit is the minimum score needed to progress (even if you are the k-th place person, you cannot progress unless your score is greater than limit).
- If there are multiple people with the same score as the k-th person with score greater than limit, they will all advance to the next round. There will be no more than 100 contestants.

Example:

```
next_round(2, 3, [1, 3, 2, 4])
next_round(10, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
```

Returns:

```
2
10
```

My code:

```
def next_round(k, limit, scores):
"""Returns number of people progressing to the next round."""
for n in scores:
    if n > limit:
        del scores[k:]
    if n < limit:
        scores.remove(n) # I think my problem is here but not sure what to do.
return len(scores)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Removing elements from the list on which you are iterating the loop is never a good idea. Because, you end up skipping indices. So, take a look at [these approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Is the last bullet worded correctly?  Shouldn't it say "If there are multiple people with the same score as the k-th person with score greater than **or equal to** limit..."?

In other words, what should `next_round(1, 2, [1, 2, 2, 2])` print?  

The way the last bullet is currently worded, that would return `1`.

With "or equal to", it would return `3`.

Comment: @RustyWidebottom Hi, that is how it has been worded in the question by my teacher. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know about the last bullet and I will update my answer accordingly.

```py
def next_round(k, limit, scores):
    """Returns number of people progressing to the next round."""
    progressing = 0

    # Look at the top k scores.
    topk = sorted(scores, reverse=True)[:k]
    for score in topk:
        if score >= limit:
            progressing += 1

    # And also include people with the same score as the k-th
    # person with score greater than limit.  (last bullet)
    rest = sorted(scores, reverse=True)[k:]
    for score in rest:
        if score == topk[-1] and score > limit:
            progressing += 1

    return progressing
```

Comment: Hi! It seems to work like mine did as well, but there is one that doesn't seem to get the right answer which is what mine is doing and this one too but I'm not sure why.

print(next_round(10, 20, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))

Should return 5 but the function is returning 0.

Comment: All the scores in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` are below the limit (20).  Therefore nobody advances.

Comment: Ohh wait sorry I got my numbers and functions mixed up! Thank you haha. :)